# Derived class in a different namespace

Tags: c++

Is there any recommendation against creating a derived in a different namespace than of its parent? Such as:

```
namespace NA {
class A {};
}

namespace NB {
class B : NA::A {}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but opinion-based questions are off-topic here.

Comment: `B` is not a subclass but a derived class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this is not opinion-based. The answer could be "it depends on your opinion" if there are no technical pros/cons, but that's a valid answer to an objective question.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Subclass and derived class are synonyms, are they not?

Comment: @Darryl I guess it could be.  I have never heard them called that before.  For some reason when I hear subclass, nested class pops into my head.

Comment: @NathanOliver Aren't subclass, inheriting, derived, descendant just different names for same concept? Nevermind, answered above.

Comment: As with a lot of programming questions of this ilk, the answer is - it depends. First you must consider whether you really need to have the derived class in a different `namespace` (i.e. what benefits does it bring?) rather than keeping it in the namespace of the base class. Just because it can be done, doesn't mean it's the best design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your code base includes multiple libraries.

If you think class A and class B should have under different namespaces (groups), kept them under different namespaces (groups). And when you need to access/ inherit one class from another, you just access/ inherit it following namespace standard.

I don't see any problems here, rather it is a good practice.

Thanks !